# how to use if else if and else in echo statement of php

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have learnt how to use if and else in echo statement using ternary operator. But This is a bit more advance from that where i need to use if, else if and else in the same echo statement.

For example:

Normal php condition:

```
if ($number == 0){
 echo "zero";
}
else{
 echo "one";
}
```

Using ternary operator:

```
(($number==0)?'zero':'one')
```

But how to convert this case using ternary operator?

```
if ($number == 0){
 echo "zero";
}
elseif ($number ==1)
 echo "one";
}
else{
 echo "two";
}
```

Comment: `$number == 0 ? 'zero' : $number == 1 ? 'one' : 'two';`

Comment: ^ Almost: `$number == 0 ? 'zero' : ($number == 1 ? 'one' : 'two');`

Comment: thank you Rizier123, its working now